# Can someone counter a creature ability with a counter target creature?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I activate a creature ability that puts creatures on the battlefield, can my opponet counter it with a counter target creature spell?

Comment: for clarification, what are the names of the cards involved?

Answer (score 6):

No, you can't counter an ability with an effect that says `counter target spell`. You can only counter a spell

One of the reasons why people play [aether vial](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=aether%20vial), because you can't counter creatures put into play with aether vial

---

You need to pay attention to the wording of the ability.  Because if the ability says that you can **"cast"** the creature such as [Garruk's Horde](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Garruk%27s%20Horde), than it does take the form of spell, and can therefore be countered.

But if the ability says to **put it onto the battlefield** than it's not a spell, and can't be countered

Comment: Given what the OP said, it probably says "counter target *creature* spell". But this is of course right - an ability putting creatures onto the battlefield is still not a creature spell.

Answer (score 2):

No, for the reasons Sam cited.  But he could probably counter it with a spell like this, if he really wanted to:

[image]

Comment: But only if you have the judge foil Stifle; normal ones aren't strong enough.